# How to make TiKZ style based REVERSE arrows similar to \draw[<-]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

How can I make **reverse style based arrows** (similar to `\draw[<-]` ) ?

The MWE below, draws a arrow from X to Y, however I want a arrow from Y to X without flipping `\draw[myarrow] (y) -- (x);` as this is not always easy possible:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with %
    {\arrow[scale=1.5,>=stealth]{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) at (3,3) {X};
\node (y) at (2,3) {Y};
\draw[myarrow] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Creates:**

[image]

**However I am looking for:**

[image]

Comment: try `\draw[myarrow] (y) -- (x);`

Comment: I have some 'legacy' figures and flipping everything is not really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this code ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{myleftarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.8 with %
    {\arrowreversed[scale=1.5,>=stealth]{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{myrightarrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.2 with %
    {\arrow[scale=1.5,>=stealth]{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) at (3,3) {X};
\node (y) at (2,3) {Y};
\draw[myleftarrow] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x) at (3,3) {X};
\node (y) at (2,3) {Y};
\draw[myrightarrow] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. This produces the same arrow reversed.